# Response from readCharacteristic is not always as expected after issue writeCharacteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm working on an android BLE app. I have a BLE device which storing the coordinates of where the device went.

In order to get the data from the device after connected, we will need to send several commands and read its response. The steps are as follow:

1. Send first command to device
2. Read response (some data..)
3. Send second command to device
4. Read response (coordinates)

And this is how I did

1. After connected, sending a command to the device by using **writeCharacteristic**
2. When receiving **GATT_SUCCESS** in **onCharacteristicWrite** callback, call **readCharacteristic** to read its response
3. When receiving **GATT_SUCCESS** in **onCharacteristicRead** callback, continue to send second command to the device by using **writeCharacteristic**
4. When receiving **GATT_SUCCESS** in **onCharacteristicWrite** callback, call **readCharacteristic** to read its response

So here's the problem, when I issued **readCharacteristic** after write operation succeeded, the response is not expected as always and sometime it return the same command that I wrote. However, if I put some delay (e.g. 1 second) after I write, the response is correct when I read but the delay may different every time.

I am wondering if anyone having the same issue like this or anyone can explain to me why is this happening? Is that possible that we can know when is the correct time to read the characteristic?

Note: The device does not provide any notification/indication.

Comment: This is probably to do with the device you're using.  When you write to a characteristic the device will likely run code on it's side and then can really do whatever it likes with the value.  So, it could ignore your write request, delay it, overwrite it, whatever.  You're probably doing everything correctly on your end.  You may want to post a question about the specific device instead.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. This question helps in my way of operation. I am trying to figure out that if we have registered setCharacteristicNotification then it does have to related to something?Need some write characteristic doc with example to analyse what exactly happening in the write operation.